# Expand submenu from top instead of dropdown

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, expand

I have a "standard" nav menu which displays submenu under it on hover, like this https://jsfiddle.net/z6vur05u/

Instead of dropdown under the menu, i would need the submenu to be pushed from top the page while moving navigation down. Closest example of this would be here http://callmenick.com/_development/slide-push-menus/ (top effect), but i simply couldnt make it work..

Code is very simple and cleaned version is here:

```
<div id="menu-wrapper">

  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent</a>
      <div>
        <div class="nav-column">
          Submenu lists here
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent</a>
      <div>
        <div class="nav-column">
          Submenu lists here
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent</a>
      <div>
        <div class="nav-column">
          Submenu lists here
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

If anybody can help out, it would mean a lot!
I played with absolute/relative positioning but i didnt get far, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you should check the tutorial/source from the link you provided? :) http://callmenick.com/post/slide-and-push-menus-with-css3-transitions

Comment: Could you please cut down on the CSS? There's a lot of CSS that's not used and because of that, I can't find the right lines to edit (of course I can, but I don't want to dig through dirt to find the gold).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've added a few lines of CSS and the result can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z6vur05u/3/).

**CSS**

```
.nav > li > div {
    [..]
    height: 0; /*added a height*/
    [..]
    top: 0px; /*changed this from 50 to 0*/
    [..]
}

.nav > li { /*completely new selector, but probably already available somewhere*/
    margin-top: 0; /*since the menu has to start at the top*/
    transition: margin-top .3s ease .15s;/*same animation as the rest, but only margin-top*/
}

.nav:hover > li { /*completely new selector, but probably already available somewhere*/
    margin-top: 250px;/*same height as the menu*/

}

.nav > li:hover > div {
    [..]
    height: 250px; /*so it animates from 0 to 250px*/
}
```

With this, you are off to a good start. You just have to add some jQuery or JS that checks if a menu-point has a submenu. If yes, add the hover-stuff, if no, don't. Now it runs the effect on hover of every menu-point.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help, but i cant see anything on your link, it behaves like it was before.Are you sure the link is correct?

Comment: That's weird! But it should be working now :) In some way it didn't save anything in update 2 on the fiddle, but it did in update 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fiddle:  [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/boweqeluco/edit?html,css,output)

1. Add jquery
2. remove `position:relative` from `.nav` class
3. change `position:relative` to `position:absolute` of class `.nav > li > div`
4. Add the following class along with the properties to your css

   `.hovered {
   margin-top:215px;
   transition: all 1s;
   }`

4.Add this piece of Jquery in your html file

```
$(function() {
$('.nav li').hover( function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().addClass("hovered");
 },
 function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("hovered");
});
});
```